# Cleveref behaviour for multilingual documents

Tags: babel, cleveref

I want to have a chapter (Extended abstract) in a foreign language (Brazilian), where all cleveref references to sections and chapters are written in Portuguese (ex. "Seção 3", "Capítulo 6").

I can make cleveref work in Portuguese, but not change the language in the middle.

See the mwe.tex:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazilian, british]{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\section{Primeira}\label{primeira}
Blablabla blabla \cref{tbl1}. Na \cref{segunda} veremos....
\selectlanguage{brazilian}
\section{Segunda}\label{segunda}
Aqui....\cref{primeira} whaaat
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Nananana} \label{tbl1}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\section{Another}
And now....\cref{segunda}
\selectlanguage{british}
\end{document}
```

Strangely, the only element referenced in Portuguese is the reference to {tbl1} which becomes "Tabela 1".

Result text:

```
1 Primeira
Blablabla blabla table 1. Na section 2 veremos....

2 Segunda
Aqui....section 1 whaaat

Tabela 1: Nananana
1 2 
3 4

3 Another
And now....section 2
```

How can I create a chapter were all the references uses names from a foreign language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is documented behavior of `cleveref` that it must also receive the language options you've informed to `babel`.  The most convenient way to do it is to give the language options to the `\documentclass`, which will be then passed to both `babel` and `cleveref` (and any other packages which may depend on them).

(However, and I may be wrong, but as far as I can tell `cleveref` has no option `british`, perhaps `english` will suffice to you).

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,brazilian,english]{article}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % if you have an up-to-date distribution, this is default
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\section{Primeira}
\label{primeira}
Blablabla blabla \cref{tbl1}. Na \cref{segunda} veremos....

\selectlanguage{brazilian}
\section{Segunda}\label{segunda}
Aqui....\cref{primeira} whaaat
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Nananana} \label{tbl1}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\selectlanguage{english}
\section{Another}
And now....\cref{segunda}

\end{document}
```

Comment: british also worked.